# 503 Services Unavailable Error While Reading Products In Shopware 6 Database Running In Docker

Tags: docker, shopware, shopware6

```
Service Unavailable
The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.
Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

I am trying to get `product` data from Shopware 6 but I get the above error every time. I am working on `docker`.

Below are my codes for reading the product table

```
public function returnProductDetails(Context $context)
    {   
        $id = "14fadb0d66204a1cb89b21ec4eed852c";
        $product = $this->productRepository->search(new Criteria([$id]), $context)->first();
        return $product;
        
    }
```

If I do the same for any other repository, It works perfectly without the `Service Unavailable` error.
Is my docker container bad?

Comment: can you access any other api route? For me it sounds like a more generic issue with your local setup

Comment: @j_elfering If I understand your question correctly, I have not tried the Admin API to access the product repository. I have no difficulty accessing other repository apart from the `product` repository. Should I delete the Shopware 6 docker images?

Comment: yep my best guess would be that you have a general setup issue here and in fact no api route from shopware is accessible, because something in your local setup is not configured correctly

Comment: deleting and rebuilding the container got everything working again.